# PHP Codeigniter image_lib; output is blank page no errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a massive headache about Codeigniter and the image_lib class. I've searched for an answer but cannot find anything. I'm working on WAMP and have gd installed. Below is my code but i can't get the image to output. Below is my code;

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd';
$config['source_image'] = './uploads/096e1f3f1a7c6feb48e0887bea3733cc.jpg';
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']     = 75;
$config['height']   = 50;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

$this->image_lib->resize();
```

When I execute this code I get a blank page. I've checked for errors; nothing is throw. The image path is correct when I do a file_exists check.

Any Ideas?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Do you have errors or warnings enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want GD2?

Make sure that the GD library is enabled with PHP. Run phpinfo() and look for a GD section. This will also tell you the version you have installed.

Comment: I have GD installed 100%. It says it supports this. Any other thoughts?

Comment: So your PHPINFO output does have a section for gd, GD Support = Enabled and GD Version = 1?

Comment: Yeaa Andrew. Its Enabled but version is (2.0.34 compatible)

Comment: I think you should try `gd2` as the image library then instead.

Comment: Hi Andrew. GD2 is installed because if I do a simple image and text it works fine.

Comment: I was referring to your code that has `$config['image_library'] = 'gd';` and that you should try `gd2` in that value instead. If that's not working, there must be something else wrong (as I can see this is basically the same exact code as they provide in the CodeIgniter documentation.)